# Google Apps Script insert Sheets data to Doc throwing error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Using the code in the Google Developer help center to insert a table into a document works fine.

```
// Create a two-dimensional array containing the cell contents.
var cells = [
  ['Row 1, Cell 1', 'Row 1, Cell 2'],
  ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2']
];

// Build a table from the array.
body.appendTable(cells);
```

However, what I need to do is insert cells from a spreadsheet as a table to my document. I've tried following other posts from here and wrote this:

```
const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID").getSheetByName("Reports");
var ssCells = sheet.getRange("A2:C5").getValues();
body.appendTable(ssCells);
```

but it throws the error "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendTable." I've logged the `ssCells` variable and it returns a normal 2d array of values, which looks in format identical to the `cells` variable from the Google example.

How do I get past this error and insert Sheets data as a table to Docs?

Comment: Where is ss defined?

Comment: maybe ```insertTable()``` instead of ```appendTable()```.

Comment: @Cooper edited. sheet === ss.

Comment: @santosOnit same issue

Comment: But it's not defined in the code. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: @Cooper I edited my code to define it. Please see that "const ss" no longer exists and has been replaced by "const sheet"

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: @Cooper It's working to dump sheet data into the doc as a table?

Comment: Solved it. One of my Sheets columns has numerical values which killed the whole thing. Using .getDisplayValues() to return the String versions and it works.

Answer (score 1):

One of my Sheets columns has numerical values which killed the whole thing. Using .getDisplayValues() to return the String versions and it works.

```
const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID").getSheetByName("Reports");
var ssCells = sheet.getRange("A2:C5").getDisplayValues();
body.appendTable(ssCells);
```